# Ошибка при создании камеры на IOS

Tags: ios

Ошибка:
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Говорят, это ошибка в iOS8. я так понимаю на выполнение программы это никак не влияет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека [LLSimpleCamera](https://github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera) (iOS8-9)